# Best post processing tool for my use case

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

TLDR: What is the best approach when it comes to post processing data that comes in constantly?

The context is as follows: part of the application I'm working on processes live data and finally writes into ElasticSearch among other values, the type of the outcome of that processing. Due to the nature of the data, X number of processings (and writings to ES) must pass in order to detect one of the specific outcomes of the mentioned processing. My task is to subsequently, after writing to ES, in a certain time range, find documents that are marked incorrectly due to the inevitable incorrect marking of documents in the phase until the anomaly is discovered.

For each range of N minutes, I would have to search multiple times over all the documents generated in that range until I find all the problematic documents.